# Create a list of users who use the same commands in discord.js

Tags: javascript, bots, discord

I am trying to make a bot on discord. And I have gotten pretty far with it.
What I can't seem to figure out is how I can get my data into lists in a JSON file.

My JSON file looks like this:

```
{
    "t7 bags": ["username1#1234", "username2#1234"],
    "t8 bags": ["username#1234"]
}
```

I need to push more "usernames" into the "t7 bags" and "t8 bags" using the message.author.id from Discord.js when they are using a certain command on discord.

I am using fs.writeFile as of now, is there a better way to do it.

```
if(message.content.startsWith(prefix + " craft")) {
    editedmessage = message.content.slice(prefix.length + 1);
    skill = message.content.slice(9);



            client.msgs [skill] = {
                users: message.author.id
                }
                message.reply("You can now " + editedmessage)
}
fs.writeFile("./msgs.json", JSON.stringify (client.msgs, null, 4), err => {
    if (err) throw err; 

    {

        return console.log(err);
    }
 })
```

This is what I am trying to use right now.

Comment: As far as I can tell it should be `client.msgs[skill].push(message.author.id);` (maybe? no idea what your specific problem is here)

Comment: It gives me this error 
`
client.msgs[skill].push(message.author.id) = {
                                           ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined 
`

Comment: what is `client.msgs` ?

Comment: client.msgs = require ("./msgs.json"); which is the file that I am writing into right now

Comment: Right now it is outputting this to the /msgs.json file 

`{
    "t10 bags": {
        "users": "95790380057894912"
    },
    "t9 bags": {
        "users": "95790380057894912"
    },
    "t8 bags": {
        "users": "95790380057894912"
    }
}`

where i want it to output more like

`{
    "t7 bags": ["username1#1234", "username2#1234"],
    "t8 bags": ["username#1234"]
}`

Comment: Ok, so put `if (!client.msgs[skill]) client.msgs[skill] = [];` before the push().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
if (message.content.startsWith (prefix + " who")) { 
    let filter = message.content.slice(prefix.length + 5) 
    let item = message.content.slice(7) 
    let _skill = client.msgs[filter]
    if(!_skill) return message.reply('Can`t find skill')
    const whoEmbed = new discord.RichEmbed() 
        .setColor('#0099ff') 
        .setTitle('These players can craft ' + item) 
        .setAuthor('VINDICTIVE CRAFTER BOT', 'https://i.imgur.com/wSTFkRM.png') 
        .setDescription(`${_skill.map(user => `<@${user}>`).join('\n')}`) 
        .setFooter('This bot was created by BigTibbies'); 
    message.channel.send(whoEmbed); 
}
```

**ADD data code**

```js
if(message.content.startsWith(prefix + " craft")) {
    let editedmessage = message.content.slice(prefix.length + 1);
    let skill = message.content.slice(9);

    if(!client.msgs[skill]) {
        client.msgs[skill] = [message.author.id]
    } else {
        if(!client.msgs[skill].includes(message.author.id)) client.msgs[skill].push(message.author.id)
    }
}
```